# In-Page Analytics (Google Analytics) Data Only Reporting Clicks, No Revenue or Transactions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

**Background:** I'm helping a client upgrade their Classic Analytics (using dc.js) to Universal Analytics and we're taking all precautions by upgrading on a staging website prior to pushing live.

We did have the live website transfer it's data to Universal Analytics in the process so when we're ready to push, it would be seamless and just a matter of validating the new universal code. My team and our client both did research and as far as we were aware, there were no issues in doing this.

**My Question:** Just a few days ago my client emailed me about their In-Page Analytics not reporting any revenue or transaction data from their ecommerece data. Click percentages are still showing up however.

My theory is that the transfer to Universal Analytics had something to do with it but I can't find any reference to this issue anywhere. There are a few variables that should be noted:

- The last time anyone used this feature was about a month ago.
- I did notice that "Enhanced Link Attribution" was turned on at some 
  point but the change history doesn't reflect when the change was
  made. So I turned it off today (didn't do anything right away it seems).
- The transfer to Universal Analytics reported as successful and no script changes were made.

Any insight, in-page analytics documentation or tests greatly appreciated!

Comment: To me it seems like the thief here was the addition of enhanced link attribution but without actually activating it. I don't actually have anything to back this statement up with, but that is where I would start my error checking! Do their regular e-commerce still function as normal?

Comment: That was my thought as well. All of their e-commerce data is still in tact and haven't experienced any issues with it. I figure it will probably fix itself once we go live with UA, but I don't even know what I should be looking for in the mean time...

Comment: Why don't you try setting up a lab enviroment and replicate the issue, and work with trying to find a work-around that way? It usually helps me in my troubleshooting. But that might be hard if you do not have access to a classic property though. I myself haven't heard anything that it should break, but perhaps the UA and Classic version isn't really mending for that particular report. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: The issue there is that my lab environment was already a UA script instead of classic - so no chance of replicating. I appreciate your insight and thoughts though.